# How do I avoid unloading a video before redirecting to another page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a video as a background for a home page, and when it loads or unloads there is a small delay where the container has a green background. I have tried to avoid this by using a preloader, and that solves the issue when the page loads, but when it redirects it still has a second where the video unloads before leaving the page, and the background is solid green

The video container:

```
<div class="site-blocks-cover overlay" data-aos="fade" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
        <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
            <source src="./images/massage.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">

                <div class="col-md-10">

                    <div class="row justify-content-center mb-4">
                        <div class="col-md-10 text-center">
                            <h1 data-aos="fade-up" class="mb-5">We give solutions to your <span class="typed-words"></span></h1>

                            <p data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100"><a href="contact.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-pill">Book Now</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the link to the live site to demonstrate: https://acrabaca.yetitech.nz/index.html

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't see a green background in Firefox when I navigate around the site.  What browsers have tested it in?

Comment: It seems to only happen in chrome, I have tested it in microsoft edge as well

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the video element before navigating away it stops the green flash in Chrome. The following piece of JavaScript adds a click handler to the anchor tags so the video is deleted before the page navigates. There is still a grey flash but it is not as jarring as the green flash. As to why it happens I am unsure.

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => {
  a.addEventListener('click', () => { 
    document.querySelectorAll('video').forEach(v => v.remove());
  });
});
```

Comment: This did work for the first click, but going back and redirecting again still has the green flash. i might just put a black overlay on the whole screen when a link is clicked